# CUDA Illegal Memory Access on PyTorch 1.3

Tags: pytorch

```
@staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
         grad_label = grad_output.clone()
        num_ft = grad_output.shape[0]
        # grad_label.data.resize_(num_ft, 32, 41)
        lin_indices_3d, lin_indices_2d = ctx.saved_variables
        num_ind = lin_indices_3d.data[0]
        grad_label.data.view(num_ft, -1).index_copy_(1, lin_indices_2d.data[1:1 + num_ind],
                                                     torch.index_select(grad_output.data.contiguous().view(num_ft, -1),
                                                                        1, lin_indices_3d.data[1:1 + num_ind]))
        # raw_input('sdflkj')
        return grad_label, None, None, None
```

This is the code snippet I am trying to run on PyTorch. However, I strangely keep getting the error of Illegal Memory Access. When I tried to use a Debugger and try and find the culprit, I would see
[image]

As such I am not certain what is wrong here. The same code was running on PyTorch 0.4 and now I am trying to run it on PyTorch 1.3 and it does not work. The same error remains on versions 1.4 and 1.5 which are the latest versions for the framework. Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was an error with PyTorch framework itself. They are going to correct it with the version 1.6

Here is the github link

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/34450